# data bind if does show div knockout js

Tags: knockout.js

So I was trying to show some divs which basically shows different color of boxes depending on the numbers they have, basically AA and B both returns 5 so they should be showing and the other divs should be blank or empty and basically not even showing the divs, but for some reason now all the data-binds dont show anything and I get empty divs.

```
                    <div>
                        <div class="riskBox1PushUp col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <div data-bind="if : AAA  > 0">    
                                <span class="riskBox1">AAA</span> <span data-bind="text : AAA"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="riskBox2PushUp col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <div data-bind="if : AA  > 0.00">  
                                <span class="riskBox2">AA</span> <span data-bind="text : AA"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="riskBox3PushUp col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <div data-bind="if : A  > 0.00">
                                <span class="riskBox3">A</span> <span data-bind="text : A"></span>
                            </div>    
                        </div>

                        <div class="riskBox2PushUp col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <div data-bind="if : B > 0.00">
                                 <span class="riskBox4">B</span> <span data-bind="text : B"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="riskBox2PushUp col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <div data-bind="if : C  > 0.00">
                                 <span class="riskBox5">C</span> <span data-bind="text : C"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="riskBox2PushUp col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <span class="riskBox6">Not invested</span> <span data-bind="text : TotalInvestment"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Not sure if this is important but the AAA and AA and so on are all ko computed.
Here is the image if I use if AA or if AAA
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to use the binding "visible" instead of "if"? Because I suspect that you might have a problem in which order the javascript executes the bindings of your variables and the if statement. Also check if `data-bind="if : AAA() > 0"` might solve your problem.

Comment: @A.Tapper yea ofcourse tried that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
data-bind="visible: AAA() > 0"
```

Answer (score 2):

I have came across this same issue few times as well. After that I always try to use either if in comments or visible binding:

For example:

```
<div class="riskBox1PushUp col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <!--ko if : AAA  > 0 -->    
                                <span class="riskBox1">AAA</span> <span data-bind="text : AAA"></span>
                            <!--/ko-->
                        </div>
```

Or with visibility:

```
<div class="riskBox1PushUp col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <!--ko visible: AAA  > 0 -->    
                                <span class="riskBox1">AAA</span> <span data-bind="text : AAA"></span>
                            <!--/ko-->
                        </div>
```

If above fails, then i suggest you re-check your variables since there is no valid reason why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

When you're evaluating the observable against a condition, you need to do:

```
data-bind="if: AAA() > 0"
```

instead of

```
data-bind="if : AAA  > 0"
```

Likewise for the other if's

Comment: Then we need to see how those observables were defined.

Answer (score 1):

When you're creating expressions that contain an observable inside a knockout binding, you need to *evaluate* the observable yourself.

I.e.: You'll need to write your data-binds in the form of: `data-bind="if: AAA() > 0"`

**Explanation:**

Knockout wraps the values you input in your binding in a function. The `AAA` in `if: AAA` becomes `function() { return AAA; }`. If this function returns an `observable` instance, it evaluates the observable's value and subscribes to changes.

When you create an expression *inside* your binding, the `observable` that might be in there gets lost in the wrapper function: `function() { return AAA > 0; }` will compare your *observable instance* to the value 0. This will simply return `false`, no matter what the observable's value is.

Comment: where do I write <!-- ko if : AAA() > 0 --> ??

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant: `data-bind="if: AAA() > 0"`. Updated

Comment: Can you show us how you're defining `AAA` in javascript?

Comment: this.AAA = ko.computed(function() {
                                    return this.DarkBlueValueR1();
                        }, this);

Comment: The other persons one worked, but thanks for the help!

Comment: Is `DarkBlueValueR1` also an observable? And why are you using a computed value to just return another value without modification?

Comment: oh sorry I forgot to paste it properly this is what I was doing 
this.AAA = ko.computed(function() { return this.DarkBlueValueR1() + "%"; }, this);

Comment: That would mean you're comparing a string to a number... `"0%" > 0` might not work as you intended. I don't think swapping out `if` for `visible` bindings will solve all of your issues...

Comment: yea thats true, there is no logic for if not working, but I really need a way out of this mess